# AutoFac and MVC IControllerActivator Needing Container

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm in an interesting situation; I need to pass the IContainer to the IControllerActivator component that I'm defining, yet the IControllerActivator needs to be registered inside of the container.  This is because the IControllerActivator will use the container to build the controllers.

I stored the container as a static reference from within the global.asax file; this way, any dependant object (like my activator) on the container can reference it.  Since the activator uses the container, and needs to be registered in an autofac module, is there a way to define that this specific mapping needs a reference to the container, or can I register this after the container is built?

What are my options here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a dependency on `IComponentContext`:

```
public Foo(IComponentContext context, ...)
```

Autofac containers automatically register themselves under this type, making it available to all components. The context instance will be the container in which `Foo` is resolved, whether it is the application-level or request-level container. This alleviates you from needing to know the scope of the container you are referencing.

Alternately, you can see if any of the [Autofac relationship types](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) serves your need. With these types in play, it is rare that you need to directly reference `IComponentContext`. This keeps your classes free of direct knowledge of Autofac.